# MS Excel 2007: how to access multiple Excel files in another Excel file and sum up from those files

Tags: excel

I want an Excel file (AllBlock.xlsx) which can collect all the data from all other files (block1.xlsx, block2.xlsx, block3.xlsx ...BlockN.xlsx) from current folder, sum those values and save in its file (AllBlock.xlsx).

Thanks in advance for answering..any help is urgently needed.

Comment: Have you worked in VBA before?  That's probably the most effective way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

we usually copy working sheets from block[1..n].xlsx to one file, such as AllBlock.xlsx, into different working sheets, and then setup functions to do the final calc.